# Installing mantis for mylyn on Zend Studio 8

Tags: php, zend-studio, mylyn, mantis

Has anyone been successful in installing the mantis connector for mylyn in Zend Studio 8? I keep getting the following error when trying to install. Please help, I understand this should boost productivity.

To install the connector I'm doing `new task >> install more connectors`

```
Problems occurred while performing installation: Operation details
Operation details
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Mylyn Tasks Connector: Mantis 3.4.1.201105131144 (com.itsolut.mantis_feature.feature.group 3.4.1.201105131144)
Software currently installed: Zend Studio 8.0.0.v20101027231 (com.zend.php.ide 8.0.0.v20101027231)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Mylyn Tasks Core 3.4.1.v20100730-0100-e3x (org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core 3.4.1.v20100730-0100-e3x)
Mylyn Tasks Core 3.5.0.v20110316-0100 (org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core 3.5.0.v20110316-0100)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Mylyn Mantis Connector UI 3.4.1.201105131144 (com.itsolut.mantis.ui 3.4.1.201105131144)
To: bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core [3.5.0,4.0.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Mylyn Tasks Connector: Mantis 3.4.1.201105131144 (com.itsolut.mantis_feature.feature.group 3.4.1.201105131144)
To: com.itsolut.mantis.ui [3.4.1.201105131144]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Zend Studio 8.0.0.v20101027231 (com.zend.php.ide 8.0.0.v20101027231)
To: org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group [3.4.2.v20100916-0100-e3x-7Z7f77FBBoPbPQeUoFeZXJ8]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Mylyn Task List (Required) 3.4.2.v20100916-0100-e3x-7Z7f77FBBoPbPQeUoFeZXJ8 (org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group 3.4.2.v20100916-0100-e3x-7Z7f77FBBoPbPQeUoFeZXJ8)
To: org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core [3.4.1.v20100730-0100-e3x]
```

Comment: Are you installing via Eclipse built in "update site" feature?

Comment: I have zend studio so the menu options may be a bit different. Mylyn in already installed Zend Studio may have come with it. I get the error when installing the connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until Zend update their bundled Mylyn version *or* decide on a better strategy you can install an older version which should be compatible with Mylyn 3.4.x . Top of my mind that should be 3.3.2, which is available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/mylyn-mantis/files/Mylyn-Mantis%20connector/mylyn-mantis-3.3.2.zip/download.

---

*Update*: I have installed a preview of Zend Studio 9 and it has much improved Mylyn integration. The latest ( 3.6.0 ) version of the MantisBT connector works just fine with it. See  [Zend Studio 9 screencast](http://ganoro.blogspot.com/2011/09/agile-web-applications-development-with.htm) and [Zend Studio 9 Early Access build #262 now available](http://ganoro.blogspot.com/2011/09/zend-studio-9-early-access-build-262.html).

Comment: Thanks, i also got the answer from zend forums from a robert, was that you?

Comment: +1 I'm using Zend Studio 9.0 and it's fantastic. The Mylyn integration is great.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Zend does not package Zend Studio using the recommended best practices.  This means that other plugins that depend on Mylyn, such as Mylyn Connectors or Tasktop, can never be installed.  Please consider filing feedback to them, asking them to fix this issue.

More details, including links to feedback mechanisms, can be found here: http://tasktop.com/support/faq/#zendStudio

Comment: hey david, i actually decided to try out mylyn  because of your presentation on cfbuilder. Im more of a php dev though so i use zend quite a bit. its a shame i can't try this out.

Comment: -1 Zend Studio has Mylyn _and_ Mylyn Connectors. I am using them.